# how to change NumberOfRowsInSection in UItableview on the basis of an empty array

Tags: ios, uitableview

i want to change number of rows in section on the basis of empty array with the help of `BOOL` if its `YES` then number of rows will increase otherwise it will remain same.But now i am facing very bad situation `Bool` is always `YES` after setting `No` But it will always `YES`.i had tried following code but nothing happens `BOOL` is always Yes.
here is my Sample code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    showLoadMoreButton=YES;

    }
-(void)LoadmoreMessagesOfInbox:(FBGenericWebHandler*)handler response:(NSDictionary*)response
{
    self.loadMore=nil;

    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    [self.imagesDictionary removeAllObjects];
    lastmessageId=[[[response objectForKey:@"messageResponse"] objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"lastMessageId"];



    if (loadMore == nil || [loadMore count] == 0)
    {
      showLoadMoreButton = NO; // here i am setting no 

    }
    for(NSDictionary *tmp in loadMore)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *messages=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [messages setValue:[tmp objectForKey:@"messageId"] forKey:@"messageId"];

    }

    for (int i=0; i<self.inboxmessagesarray.count; i++)
    {
        [self.lblArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell Number %d",i]];
        [self.totalcheckmarkArray addObject:@"NO"]; // May b
    }
    }
    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{
    if(showLoadMoreButton)
    {

    return self.inboxmessagesarray.count+1;// control always come here 
    }
    else
        return self.inboxmessagesarray.count;

}
```

Comment: `[yourTableview reloadData];` don't go for check or something...

Comment: Can you please put your `response Dictionary`in question, as it will be helpful.?

Comment: you want to show Loading cell while the data is being downloaded?

Comment: your if condition doesn't execute may be..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After changing the value of showLoadMoreButton, you should write `[self.tableView reloadData];` to reload the data in the tableview.

For example:

```
showLoadMoreButton = NO;

[tableView reloadData];
```

Hope this helps!

Jason

**EDIT**

There may not be a need for the showLoadMoreButton variable. In your tableview: numberOfRowsInSection: method...

```
return (loadMore == nil || [loadMore count] == 0) ? self.inboxmessagesarray.count+1 : self.inboxmessagesarray.count;
```

Comment: I m not jst reloading table view thanx for all comments

Answer (score 1):

first check your loadMore array have data or not

simple try this. why to use unwanted code

if data present execute else part

```
if (loadMore == nil || [loadMore count] == 0)
    {
      showLoadMoreButton = NO; 
    [yourTable reloadData];

    }


 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{
    if([loadMore Count]==0)
    {

    return self.inboxmessagesarray.count+1;// control always come here 
    }
    else
        return self.inboxmessagesarray.count;

}
```

Comment: @coderact -- problem is not here , the table does not refresh in correctly